# Is it normal for a http GET request to take between 1 and 3 seconds when my ping to the host is under 1ms?

Tags: java, http, netbeans, okhttp

I'm writing a java application which needs to be very efficient when it does http GET requests.

I'm using netbeans profile feature which lets me measure performance and I've tried 2 libraries so far: the java default one and okhttp.

I've noticed that for every request, it takes between 1 and 3 seconds between the point where I start building the url and executing the connection and the point where I receive the response code. Isn't this a bit too much ? Also, please note that the ping between my pc and the host is less than 1 ms. How can openConnection() / execute() method take so long ? Is it even normal and how can I make it faster ?

This is how I do it with okhttp. OkHttpClient client is created only once, when I start the app

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            jresp = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

            response.close();            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And this is the version using java default library

```
try {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            URL url = new URL(buyUrl);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            BufferedReader rd;

            int code = conn.getResponseCode();


            if (code == 200) {
                rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            } else {
                rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
            }

            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();

            jresp = new JSONObject(result.toString());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Both methods take the same time on average as I said, between 1000 and 3000 ms

Comment: It all depends on how you do the request. Please post your code.

Comment: It also depends on what the server needs to do to produce the response. If the server is slow, you can't really do anything.

Comment: I'd suggest using a tool like Curl and/or WireShark to trace the request. If it's a server side issue there isn't much you can do. You can have a fast ping time but the server could be executing a slow query. I've seen servers take minutes to respond to get requests! You can also add some logging to your code with timestamps to see exactly what is taking so long.

Comment: There are so many different possibilities and causes for this that it's too broad for this site.

Comment: Code added in the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [OkHttp EventListener](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Events) or implement tracing with libraries like Zipkin to understand why it's taking time at all levels.

I can't answer with specifics for your particular case, without access to your network or server.

This is a sample OkHttp request to http://news.google.com

[image]

Reasons it is slow

- Includes a redirect from http to https
- Does two DNS lookups (which could be a lot slower)
- Creates two TCP sockets (relevant where in the world we are connecting to)
- Does 1 TLS handshake
- Google redirects from http://news.google.com to http://news.google.com/ to https://news.google.com/ to https://news.google.com/news/?ned=us&gl=US&hl=en
- Transferring response data is slow (4x)

Things you could do to speed up this particular request

- Know to hit to final endpoint first time
- Reuse an existing HTTP/2 connection

[image]

Comment: I've tried it but when I click Find traces , it shows nothing.

Comment: That was just an example, if you want to use Zipkin you need to implement your own Tracing e.g. https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/baulsupp/oksocial/tracing/ZipkinTracingListener.kt

Comment: Probably simpler just to print out events e.g. https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Events

Comment: The EventListener was extremely helpful and easy to use. The first connection takes more than the others because there's the handshake. The others still take at least one second, but that's because the server takes some time to send the response body(even if it is relatively small). The connectionAcquired and requestHeaders callback are execute within a few ms, so my issue is solved. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: One last thing, if there is no request for a certain amount of time, say 5 minutes, the first request which is made takes around 100 ms to acquire connection. If there is another request quickly after this one, everything goes back to "normal" and connection is acquired in under 2-3 ms. How can I assure the connection is always established under 3 ms ? Should I do intermediate requests even if not indeed in order mantain the connection alive ?